# iOS - Swift - FSCalendar Strange space between day's names and day's numbers

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

Currently I'm working on an iOS app, and I'm encountering a problem with FSCalendar module.
After calendar init, a strange space between day's names and day's numbers.
This space disappear after any touch or swipe screen.
Actually the space take place in the view FSCalendar and doesn't concern others view.
I have colored in blue the background view to show that the problem is in the view FSCalendar.

Anyone else can help me ?
This is a screen shot of my problem and the link of this module.

https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

[strange space between day's names and day's numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XFTy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you have the same issue with some users of [JTAppleCalendar](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar).

After looking into the problem, i see this in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)

[image]

Therefore, is it possible for your app that you can **deselect** this option only for the viewController that your calendar is on?

[image]

This will fix your problem.
This problem usually happens when you have the calendar on a ViewController that is backed by a navigation contntroller somewhere on the view hierarchy.